# Unity atlases .mat and .prefab no tracked by git

Tags: unity-game-engine

## Our problem!

We have develop game on iOS and Android, Our problem is update atlases maker on Windows then commit it to git and after that pull it on MAC OSX for iOS version but .mat and .prefab no tracked by git, the result is no changed on MAC OSX, we should did it again on MAC OSX

## Trying

1. We have tried it "git rm -r --cached", it's not working
2. Add !*.prefab and !*.mat to .gitignore file, it's not working too.
3. Last way is remove and commit it and add file and commit it again. it's not a good way but it working.

## .gitignore file

```
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/

# Autogenerated VS/MD solution and project files
/*.csproj
/*.unityproj
/*.sln
/*.suo
/*.user
/*.pidb
UnityProj.userprefs

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt
AuthInfo.txt

!*.prefab
!*.mat
```

Have anyone any ideas to better way? please!

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354561/why-cannot-i-load-obj-file-to-my-repository)

I had same problem. Maybe your problem is same with it. just check if there a global .gitignore file in folder where your git projects are in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved!, 
When i change prefab and apply it, Unity Editor not change the .prefab file, it's will created file when close Editor or save the scene or save project.